# Quantization using tensorflow lite not working as expected

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, quantization

I need to deploy a CNN model on a microntroller, so I'm trying to perform post training, 8 bit full integer quantization using tensorflow lite. However, as shown in the image, the predictions are going completely wrong. This is the code I'm using for converting and predicting using the converted model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

# Create a representative dataset with values in range [0, 1]
input_shape = (1, 23, 256, 1)  # Update with your input shape

# Generate a random representative data array with values in range [0, 1]
representative_data = np.random.random_sample(input_shape).astype(np.float32)

# Provide representative dataset for quantization
def representative_dataset_gen():
    yield [representative_data]

model=load_model('cnn_fivelayer_2class.h5',compile=False)

#quantization
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
# Ensure that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
# Set the input and output tensors to uint8 (APIs added in r2.3)
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()

#prediction
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model_quant)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details=interpreter.get_input_details()[0]
output_details=interpreter.get_output_details()[0]

input_data=np.ones((1,23,256,1),dtype=np.uint8)

input_shape = input_details['shape']
#input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.uint8)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details['index'])

scale, zero_point = output_details['quantization']
dequantized_value= scale * (output_data - zero_point)
```

However, the predictions (i.e the dequantized value) are completely off:

[image]

Is there something wrong with the code or should I attribute this to the loss in accuracy faced by models after post training quantization? In this case the predictions are like, totally inverted so I'm leaning towards something being wrong with the code.